# Show/Hide columns of GridView on checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, gridview, checkbox

*I have created checkbox for each column of gridview.
On UnCheck of a checkbox, I am hiding a related column to that checkbox
and On Check of it, I m again Showing that particular column*

**In my code, I m using separate javascript function for each checkbox's operations,
So, my question is : Is there a way so that I Can have only 1 js function for all checkboxes ???? (Something like Accessing DOM element using jquery index based method)**

**here is my code**

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#chk1").click(function () {
                 $("table tr").find("th:eq(0)").toggle();
                 $("table tr").find("td:eq(0)").toggle();
             });
             $("#chk2").click(function () {
                 $("table tr").find("th:eq(1)").toggle();
                 $("table tr").find("td:eq(1)").toggle();
             });
             $("#chk3").click(function () {
                 $("table tr").find("th:eq(2)").toggle();
                 $("table tr").find("td:eq(2)").toggle();
             });
             $("#chk4").click(function () {
                 $("table tr").find("th:eq(3)").toggle();
                 $("table tr").find("td:eq(3)").toggle();
             });
             $("#chk5").click(function () {
                 $("table tr").find("th:eq(4)").toggle();
                 $("table tr").find("td:eq(4)").toggle();
             });
         });
    </script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div align="center">
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" Text="Id" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk2" Text="Name" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk3" Text="Password" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk4" Text="Email Id" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk5" Text="Designation" Checked="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Emp Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Emp Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpPassword" HeaderText="Password" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[id^='chk']").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var res = id.substring(3, 4);

  $("table tr").find("th:eq("+(parseInt(res)-1)+")").toggle();
  $("table tr").find("td:eq("+(parseInt(res)-1)+")").toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here I added a common class and value for all the check boxes : Try this:**

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {

         $(".cbox").click( function() {
     var cbox_val = $(this).val();  //Get the current checkbox value 0,1,2..

       //Add these to selector       
        $("table tr").find("th:eq("+cbox_val+")").toggle();  
        $("table tr").find("td:eq("+cbox_val+")").toggle();
  });

         });
    </script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div align="center">

     <asp:CheckBox class="cbox" value="0" ID="chk1" Text="Id" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox class="cbox" value="1" ID="chk2" Text="Name" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox class="cbox" value="2" ID="chk3" Text="Password" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox class="cbox" value="3" ID="chk4" Text="Email Id" Checked="true" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox class="cbox" value="4" ID="chk5" Text="Designation" Checked="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Emp Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Emp Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpPassword" HeaderText="Password" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: var cbox_val = $(this).val();  //Get the current checkbox value 0,1,2..

Checkbox is either checked or unchecked, so what does the above line mean ??????

Still my prob is not solved .:(

Comment: $(this).val(); will return the value of check box checked while clicking. Suppose if clicked first check box, it will return '0; . Because we setting the attribute value of the first check box as '0'.

Comment: It doesnt work, b'coz $(this).val() doesnt get which checkbox we are trying to access.

Error is : Not able to show/hide columns anymore with your code...

Had u understand my Question properly ?????

Comment: [1]. Could you please alert the "cbox_val" ?                       [2]. Did you added attribute for check box ->  class="cbox" value="0" ?

Comment: alert(cbox_val) doesnt show anything !!!! please read my question thoroughly !!!!

Comment: I have already provided the code, only script section changes are as follows as u said so.... Still not working ....

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

         $(".cbox").click( function() {
     var cbox_val = $(this).index();  //Get the current checkbox value 0,1,2..

       //Add these to selector       
        $("table tr").find("th:eq("+cbox_val+")").toggle();  
        $("table tr").find("td:eq("+cbox_val+")").toggle();
  });
    </script>

n BTW the  prob is solved by vintot..... n thnx 4 help

Comment: Ok great! That is one more approach. But still I think you missed out the class and value attributes in <asp:Checkbox> tag.